# Can't get Intel AX200 Wifi Adapter working on clean installation of 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi

Fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 on a HP 840 G6 laptop. Turned off Fast Boot in BIOS.  No dual boot; no Windows installed; formatted hard drive upon Ubuntu installation.  Seems what I am reading is this is an error with Dual Boot - but I don't have this: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Airplane mode is off. I installed the Intel drivers via instructions on this page: https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-intel-wifi-6-ax200-driver/.  Ethernet (wired) works just fine.  I don't even see the Wifi icon in my system manager.

Here's what I checked:

uname -sr:

```
Linux 5.15.0-56-generic
```

lshw -C networks:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e8000000-e8003fff
```

lspci:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

rfkill list:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: Memory at e8000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

modinfo mt7921e | grep alias:

```
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000616sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007922sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007961sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

sudo dmesg | grep iwl:

```
[    4.495191] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    4.495192] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
[    4.662196] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.999413] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: CSR_RESET = 0x10
[    4.999418] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
[    4.999539] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f7f8c30
[    4.999589] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f7f0030
[    4.999654] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f7f8c30
[    4.999788] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f7f8030
[    4.999915] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f7f0430
[    5.000035] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f7f0c30
[    5.000081] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f7f8c32
[    5.000127] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f7f0832
[    5.000174] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f7f8c32
[    5.000221] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f7f8832
[    5.000284] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f7f8832
[    5.000418] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f7f8430
[    5.000538] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f7f0830
[    5.000607] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f7f0832
[    5.000742] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f7f8430
[    5.000744] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
[    5.000879] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001001] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001070] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001205] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001340] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001475] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001596] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001647] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001698] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001749] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001801] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001852] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001903] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x044466c2
[    5.001972] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x044466c2
[    5.002107] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x044466c2
[    5.002109] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
[    5.002244] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0xb00c4c71
[    5.002380] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0xe00c4c71
[    5.002501] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0xb00c4c71
[    5.002552] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0xa00c4c71
[    5.002603] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0xf00c4c71
[    5.002654] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0xb00c4c71
[    5.002707] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0xe00c4c71
[    5.002831] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0xa00c4c71
[    5.002882] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0xe00c4c71
[    5.002952] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0xb00c4c71
[    5.003086] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0xe00c4c71
[    5.003221] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0xb00c4c71
[    5.003360] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0xe00c4c71
[    5.003486] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0xb00c4c71
[    5.003606] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0xf00c4c71
[    5.003609] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
[    5.003661] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000000
[    5.003885] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:3a:00.0 failed with error -110
```

sudo dmesg | grep iwl:

```
[    4.520119] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.533676] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.533696] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    4.534046] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.678807] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    5.356947] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 0
[    5.358645] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.049407] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 1
[    6.050674] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.733507] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 2
```

firmware:

```
iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-67.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-71.ucode
```

Here is sudo dmesg | grep iwl currently:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.520119] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.533676] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.533696] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    4.534046] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.678807] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    5.356947] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 0
[    5.358645] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.049407] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 1
[    6.050674] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.733507] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 2
```

... and here it is with a cold startup:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for silverfox: 
[    4.426219] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.439899] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.439912] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    4.440153] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.639044] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    5.335236] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 0
[    5.337682] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.037278] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 1
[    6.039448] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.757460] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: retry init count 2
```

Comment: Please do: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` Next, reboot and show us a new version: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Completed the two tasks.  Added updated version of sudo dmesg | grep iwl above.  Thank you!

Comment: Which firmware files do you have? `ls /lib/firmware | grep cc-a0` In addition to -66, the latest linux-firmware package includes 67, 68 and 71.

Comment: Firmware added above.

Comment: Is there any difference in dmesg between a reboot and a cold boot; i.e. shut down completely, wait a few moments and start with the power button?

Comment: Added the code above.  It doesn't look like it's different.  As Ubuntu was starting up, I "think" I saw the same "retry" error come up just before the login screen.  It was fast, but I think it was the same....

Comment: Bumping for visibility...  anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this resolved.  I'm not sure what happened, but I restarted my computer about two weeks later, and I'm able to use my Wifi.